# MVC LINQ Sort / OrderBy a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

the for each loop works properly setting the `PickupDistanceSort` column correctly, but then I can't get the model to sort so that I can display the rows in ascending order based on the newly set `PickupDistanceSort` values.  `PickupDistanceSort` is a data type of long.  The model displays in the view, it's just not sorted.  **How do you sort a model before it's sent to the view?**

```
    public ActionResult JobsDistanceSorted()
    {            
        var model = from j in db.Jobs select j;

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            item.PickupDistanceSort = ICN.CustomMethods.
                   GetDistance(34.180046081543, -118.309028625488,
                   item.PickupLatitude, item.PickupLongitude);
        }

        model = model.OrderBy(s => s.PickupDistanceSort);
        return View("JobHeadings", model);
    }
```

Comment: what type of `PickupDistanceSort`?

Comment: Are you sure that GetDistance() method is returning value correctly?

Comment: yes, GetDistance returns correct values, i can see them fine in the View, I just can't get the model / view to sort on those values.

Comment: PickupDistanceSort is a double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert it to List which stores items locally, and then you can call OrderBy on local list. Calling OrderBy on IQueryable will result in new database query, in which the values are not stored.

```
public ActionResult JobsDistanceSorted()
{            
    var model = db.Jobs.ToList();

    foreach (var item in model)
    {
        item.PickupDistanceSort = ICN.CustomMethods.
               GetDistance(34.180046081543, -118.309028625488,
               item.PickupLatitude, item.PickupLongitude);
    }
    return View("JobHeadings", model.OrderBy(s => s.PickupDistanceSort));
}
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<ICN.Job>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ICN.Job>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\ICN\ICN August\ICN August\Controllers\JobController.cs 124 21 ICN

Comment: I can't save it back to the database because the values are just temporary and are different for each user.  So, I tried you 2nd suggestion but got the error above.

Answer (score 0):

If `PickupDistanceSort` is not a .Net type you need to imlement an `IEqualityComparer` for your type and use `OrderBy` like this (PickupDistanceComparer is the name of your custom comparer):

```
model = mode.OrderBy(s => s.PicupDistanceSort, new PickupDistanceComparer());
```

Comment: PickupDistanceSort is a double, that's the type the call to GetDistance returns.  Here is the Model definition: public virtual double PickupDistanceSort { get; set; }